# Aspect extraction and Vector Space Model

Tags: sentiment-analysis, tf-idf, word2vec, vsm

I have a dataset of reviews like:

```
"Teacher","Subject","Feedback"    
"Dr.Reddy","DSP","He has very good subject knowledge. He didn't take all the lectures. He teaches and explains concepts very well."    
"Ms. Vibha","OOPS","She is very regular with classes. But she does not teach in an easy way."
```

Is it possible to extract aspects(features) from this data along with opinion words using any Vector Space Model (Word2Vec, Tf-idf, etc.)?